# Currency Convert issue facing again and again

Tags: razor, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I have class which help to convert usd to inr now which are giving error now which is this:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

On this line code line:

```
var result = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1]
```

Here is a full class:

```
public static decimal CurrencyConvert(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
     //Grab your values and build your Web Request to the API
     string apiURL = String.Format("http://finance.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}&meta={3}", amount, fromCurrency, toCurrency, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
     //Make your Web Request and grab the results
     var request = WebRequest.Create(apiURL);         
     //Get the Response
     var streamReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
     //Grab your converted value (ie 2.45 USD)
     var streamData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     var result = Regex.Matches(streamData, "<span class=\"?bld\"?>([^<]+)</span>")[0].Groups[1].Value;
     //Get the Result
     return Convert.ToDecimal(result.Replace(" INR", ""));
}
```

Comment: I'll suggest to separate the regular expression from the matches resolution and you will see the error. Something like:  var matches = Regex.Matches(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), input); if (matches.Count() > 0 ){var match = matches[0]; if(match.Groups.Count() >= 2){var group = match.Groups[1]}}

Comment: its error about APIurl but i didn't getting fix Api Url for it

Comment: If you split your logic using variables as I suggested you will see the exact problem. I think that the web request bring a response content with no matches for your Regex.